# C# Word SaveAs RPC server is unavailable

Tags: c#, ms-word

```
private void CreateDocument(string date, string name, string phone, string father_name, string address, string village, string post, string taluka, string city, string district, string pincode, string product, int price)
        {
string currentPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
            // Get the Word application object.
            Word._Application word_app = new Word.Application();

                // Make Word visible (optional).
                word_app.Visible = true;

                // Create the Word document.
                object missing = Type.Missing;
                Word._Document word_doc = word_app.Documents.Add(
                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

                // Create a header paragraph.
                Word.Paragraph para = word_doc.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);
                //para.Range.Text = "Chrysanthemum Curve";
                object style_name = "Heading 1";
                para.Range.set_Style(ref style_name);
                para.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

            // Add more text.
                  para.Range.Text = "";
                para.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

                // Save the current font and start using Courier New.
                string old_font = para.Range.Font.Name;
                para.Range.Font.Name = "Courier New";

            // Add the equations.
            para.Range.Font.Bold = 1;
            para.Range.Font.Size = 16;
                para.Range.Text = "EXPRESS PARCEL WITH COD" +"\v" + "ADVANCE PAYMENT" + "\v" + "CODE NO 560023100235" + "\v" + "BOOKING AT PBC BG 560046" + "\v" + "COD FOR RS " + price + "/ -" + "\v" + "PLEASE COLLECT CASH " + price + "/-" + "\v" + "(" + NumberToWords(price) + ")" + "\v" + "BILLER 5792" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;


                // Start a new paragraph and then
                // switch back to the original font.
                para.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
            para.Range.Font.Name = "Courier New";
            para.Range.Font.Bold = 1;
            para.Range.Font.Size = 16;
            para.Range.Text = "TO\v" + name + father_name + "\v" + address + "\v" + village + "\v" + post + "\v" + taluka + "\v" + city + "\v" + district + "\v" + "PINCODE-" + pincode + "\v" + "MOBILE-" + phone + Environment.NewLine+Environment.NewLine;


            // Start a new paragraph and then
            // switch back to the original font.
            para.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
            para.Range.Font.Name = "Times New Roman";
            para.Range.Font.Size = 12;
            para.Range.Text = "FROM" + "\v" + "AVK SHOPPING PVT LTD" + "\v" + "NO U16, BHUVANESHWARINAGAR" + "\v" + "MAGADI ROAD BANGALORE - 23" + Environment.NewLine+Environment.NewLine+ Environment.NewLine+ Environment.NewLine;

            // Start a new paragraph and then
            // switch back to the original font.           para.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
            para.Range.Font.Name = "Times New Roman";
            para.Range.Font.Size = 12;
            para.Range.Text = "PARCEL CONTAINS" + " (" + product + ") " + "AND  THE PARCEL DO" + "\v" + "NOT CONTAIN ANY DANGEROUS ARTICLE PROHIBITED BY" + "\v" + "POSTAL REGULATIONS";


            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            //if(!(File.Exists(@currentPath + name + date + ".docx")))
            //{

            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    //File.Create(@currentPath + name + date + ".docx");

            //}
            string filename = name + "-" + phone + "-" + ".docx";
            MessageBox.Show(currentPath);
            object ob = @currentPath + filename;
            word_doc.SaveAs2(ref ob);
                MessageBox.Show("Document created successfully !");

            // Close.

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(word_doc);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(word_app);
         }
```

The above code is working good but some times at `word_doc.SaveAs2(ref ob);`its giving error **The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)'** I already checked few suggestion but none of them solved my rpc issue.

Also once the .docx file was creating it is opening automatically. I don't want to open .docx once its created the file because my tool create 100 files at a time. If every doc opens my pc will use so many resources. (Simply I want to save the file silently).

This is windowsforms - vs2017 I am using.

Comment: Please take a moment to review the site rules about asking questions in the [help]. Only one question / Question is allowed. Ask your second question in a *new* question. And please check that you tag it correctly - *read* the tag information about what a tag is for.

Comment: What is the context in which this code runs? WPF? Winforms? Web project?

Comment: It is windows forms.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't properly release all the COM objects generated in the code  then this can happen when code is executed more than once without going out of scope. The error indicates that the `Application` object (RPC Server) is still being used and therefore cannot be instantiated

The code orphans the object `para`, for example. So `para` can "block" the `word_app` object.

When using C# it's also a good idea to use specific objects instead of dot-notation so that they can be explicitly released, as well. (It's also more efficient.) For example, instead of `para.Range.Font`

```
Word.Range paraRange = para.Range;
Word.Font paraFont = paraRange.Font;
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion still same issue. Also tried Close(ref save_changes, ref missing, ref missing); and .quick functions still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ExportAsFixedFormat` instead of `SaveAs2`.

Example:

```cs
wrdDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat(
    @pdffileName,
    WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF,
    false,
    WdExportOptimizeFor.wdExportOptimizeForPrint,
    WdExportRange.wdExportAllDocument,
    0,
    0,
    WdExportItem.wdExportDocumentContent
);
```

Answer (score -1):

When you encounter this exception, have you closed the document? This severs the connection to Word. Since you encounter this occasionally rather than consistently (and you state that you don't want the documents to open in the first place) I suspect that this is the case.

For what it's worth, I'd recommend not using Word automation for this at all and just using the zipped XML that compose the docx files directly. Unless you have to explicitly support pre-2007 versions of Microsoft Word, I don't know why you couldn't do this given the constraints you posted. When we made that transition in 2007, the documents that required 45 minutes to create via automation took 15 seconds on the same hardware largely because the automation objects have to account for so many things outside of your specific use case.

Comment: Whether the document is open or closed, the connection to Word is not severed. Looking at the code it's clear that the document is *not* closed, nor the Word application exited. The result, as far as visibility is concerned, is that the Word application is open with the document visible. `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` is what is severing the connections - but not all COM objects are being released.